# HR Schema sample DB, not displaying HR tables when expanding tables tree?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to this but I just installed Oracle Database 19c and SQL Developer. I am successfully connected to the HR sample schema. I can query against the HR tables such as HR.EMPLOYEES, etc.. However, in the Connections pane, when I expand the tables under this connection, there is a long list of tables starting with AQ$_INTERNET_AGENTS_PRIVS and a big list of other tables, but I can't see any of the HR tables? Where are they? Is this a view setting maybe?

This is for practice/homework. While it still seems to work, I can't figure out what the problem is. Researched here and other locations on the web.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually connect as HR, not as SYS or some other privileged user? (Incidentally, you wouldn't need the `HR.` schema prefix to see `EMPLOYEES` etc. if you were connect as HR.) If you are connected as SYS, create a new connection, and only use that. [This might be helpful.](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm)

Comment: Ok, I think this must be it because when I drop the HR. prefix, I get "table or view does not exist".

Comment: That was it! I made a new connection with user credentials and now it's good to go with tables as expected. Thanks so much Alex!

Answer (score 0):

The UI shows you the tables (and other objects) that belong to the schema for the user you have logged into.

So if you login in as HR, you'll see the tables for HR.

Otherwise if you want to see objects belonging to a different schema, navigate to the 'Other Users' node.

[image]

Or if you have synonyms in your schema which point to tables in another schema, you can ask SQL Developer to display those

[image]

And now when I look at my Tables list for my user that doesn't have any tables..

[image]

I talk about this in a bit more detail [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/).